# zcreating htaccess for subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, zebra-printers

Currently we are having domain like www.mydomain.com, in this we create sub domain like    subdomain.mydomain.com

in main domain we having seperate site and htaccess files there and another in sub domain we having seperate site and htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

This is my htaccess file in sub domain to redirect page to sub domain index page but it redirect to www.mydomain.com index page how to write the htaccess for the sum domain, what is the problem in this htaccess file

And we are using **Zend framework**

Answer (score 0):

It's not `mod_rewrite` (the quoted configuration), what is doing the redirect to main site. Check your Zend Framework application configuration and/or possible other rewrite rules.